# Getting started with gcutil and Compute Engine: Error: The resource 'projects/<project-id>' was not found

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-compute-engine

I am attempting to get up and running with Google Compute Engine and am following the [getting started/hello world tutorial](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/hello_world). After installing gcutil (running OSx) and [Authenticating to Google Compute Engine](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/#auth) the instruction is to pass the following command

```
$ gcutil getproject --project=<project-id> --cache_flag_values
```

However the following error message is returned

```
Error: The resource 'projects/<project-id>' was not found
```

Where project-id is the id of the project authenticated earlier. If I then try to execute any of the following commands in the tutorial (but including the project-id because cashing the value failed) e.g.

```
$ gcutil addfirewall http2 --project=<project-id> --description="Incoming http allowed." --allowed="tcp:http"
```

The same error gets returned.

I am working in the $HOME directory (the same directory that contains the gcutil-1.8.0 folder).

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting the projects not found error, and if possible how to overcome it?

Comment: Try re-running the failed gcutil command with the --dump_request_response option and see if that gives any clues. If not, send a transcript (minus any sensitive info, like ssh key, OAUth token, etc.) to gc-team@google.com and we can take a look there.

Comment: Cheers Marc, email sent.

Answer (score 4):

Visit your project's "Compute Engine" page once, then run the command again:

```
$ gcutil getproject --project=<project-id> --cache_flag_values
```

for me. it works.

Comment: surprisingly... same here

Answer (score 2):

You must first enable billing in order to use Compute Engine.

https://console.developers.google.com/billing

Comment: Visit your project's "Compute Engine" page once, then run the command again

Answer (score 1):

Often you'll see this error when there is an authentication/authorization failure.

Make sure you ensure that the user account gcutil is authorized as matches a user account listed in the teams section of the (Cloud Console)[https://cloud.google.com/console].  You can find that under the gear icon in the upper right corner.

To confirm which account is being used by gcutil, run the following command:

```
$ gcutil auth --confirm_email --just_check_auth
INFO: Authorization succeeded for user xxx@xxx.com
```

If you find that you are authorized under the wrong account (multiple personas in chrome, for example) you can reauthorize gcutil with:

```
$ gcutil auth
```

Make sure that you follow this link in the right browser tab/context.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your input. I followed the directions but can confirm that the authorisation succeeded for the correct user that is the owner of the app in the teams section. I tend to do these things in incognito to ensure user id's don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can Used Two Steps:

Step 1: You will enable billing in order to use `Compute Engine`.

Step 2: And visit your project's `Compute Engine` page once, then run the command again.

it works Fine for me.